# Вызвать функцию из подключенного js файла

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть два файла **main.js** и **second.js**. Как правильно подключить к html странице файл second.js и затем, вызвать расположенную в нём функцию **my_function();**?

Подключаю таким способом:

Файл **main.js**

```
var new_script = document.createElement('script');
new_script.type = 'text/javascript';
new_script.src = 'http://site.ru/second.js';
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
head.appendChild(new_script);
// дальше сразу же вызываю функцию расположенную в файле second.js
// выходит следующая ошибка - Предполагается наличие объекта
my_function();
```

Файл **second.js**

```
function my_function() {
   alert("HELLO");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено:

```
if(new_script.readyState) {
    new_script.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if(new_script.readyState == "loaded" || new_script.readyState == "complete") {
            new_script.onreadystatechange = null;
            my_function();
        }
    };
} else {
    new_script.onload = function () {
            my_function();
    };
}
```